# C# Regular Expression pattern is not working

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

Here is my pattern. It doesn't seems to be working. I am basically looking the colorcode to be 2 to 3 alphanumeric. but this doesn't seems to be working.

```
^(?<productno>\d{6})\s(?<mattype>\w+).*?(\s)?((?<colorcode>[A-Z0-9]{3})|(?<viewcode>\(view\d+\))*)(?:_[A-Z])?$
```

With the result:

```
123456 STLI Ocean EHC_Q 
colorcode: EHC is valid
123456 STLI Ocean EHCD_Q 
colorcode: HCD is invalid
```

Can anyone help me how to make it work so that the colorcode should be 2 to 3 alphanumeric?

Valid test datas:

```
123456 STLI_Q
123456 STLI Ocean EHC_Q
123456 STLI White WE_Q
123456 FMV SPIN FUCHSIA 2YP
123456 STLI (view002)_Q
123456 STL AQUA WBP
```

Thanks

Comment: Try [`^(?<productno>\d{6})\s(?<mattype>\w+).*?\s*(?:(?<viewcode>\(view\d+\))|(?<colorcode>[A-Z0-9]{2,3}))(?:_[A-Z])?$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3cproductno%3e%5cd%7b6%7d)%5cs(%3f%3cmattype%3e%5cw%2b).*%3f%5cs*(%3f%3a(%3f%3cviewcode%3e%5c(view%5cd%2b%5c))%7c(%3f%3ccolorcode%3e%5bA-Z0-9%5d%7b2%2c3%7d))(%3f%3a_%5bA-Z%5d)%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=507920+STLI_Q%0d%0a158035+STLI+Ocean+EHC_Q%0d%0a158035+STLI+White+WE_Q%0d%0a306002+FMV+SPIN+FUCHSIA+2YP%0d%0a507918+STLI+(view002)_Q%0d%0a306002+STL+AQUA+WBP&o=m)

Comment: Or maybe [`^(?<productno>\d{6})\s(?<mattype>\w+).*?\s*(?:(?<viewcode>\(view\d+\))|(?<colorcode>\b[A-Z0-9]{2,3}))(?:_[A-Z])?$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3cproductno%3e%5cd%7b6%7d)%5cs(%3f%3cmattype%3e%5cw%2b).*%3f%5cs*(%3f%3a(%3f%3cviewcode%3e%5c(view%5cd%2b%5c))%7c(%3f%3ccolorcode%3e%5cb%5bA-Z0-9%5d%7b2%2c3%7d))(%3f%3a_%5bA-Z%5d)%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=507920+STLI_Q%0d%0a158035+STLI+Ocean+EHC_Q%0d%0a158035+STLI+White+WE_Q%0d%0a306002+FMV+SPIN+FUCHSIA+2YP%0d%0a507918+STLI+(view002)_Q%0d%0a306002+STL+AQUA+WBP%0d%0a123456+STLI+Ocean+EHCD_Q&o=m)?

Comment: No. it is not working. It still getting HCD if it ends with EHCD_Q.

Comment: The second works but it makes the whole match as failure. I want it to be success but the colorcode group has to be empty if it is not 2 to 3 alphanumeric

Comment: I guess this should be fine. Thank you

Comment: This [`^(?<productno>\d{6})\s(?<mattype>\w+).*?\s*(?:(?<viewcode>\(view\d+\))|(?<colorcode>\b[A-Z0-9]{2,3}))?(?:_[A-Z])?$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3cproductno%3e%5cd%7b6%7d)%5cs(%3f%3cmattype%3e%5cw%2b).*%3f%5cs*(%3f%3a(%3f%3cviewcode%3e%5c(view%5cd%2b%5c))%7c(%3f%3ccolorcode%3e%5cb%5bA-Z0-9%5d%7b2%2c3%7d))%3f(%3f%3a_%5bA-Z%5d)%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=507920+STLI_Q%0d%0a158035+STLI+Ocean+EHC_Q%0d%0a158035+STLI+White+WE_Q%0d%0a306002+FMV+SPIN+FUCHSIA+2YP%0d%0a507918+STLI+(view002)_Q%0d%0a306002+STL+AQUA+WBP%0d%0a123456+STLI+Ocean+EHCD_Q&o=m)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use

```
^(?<productno>\d{6})\s(?<mattype>\w+).*?\s*(?:(?<viewcode>\(view\d+\))|(?<colorcode>\b[A-Z0-9]{2,3}))?(?:_[A-Z])?$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3Cproductno%3E%5Cd%7B6%7D)%5Cs(%3F%3Cmattype%3E%5Cw%2B).%2A%3F%5Cs%2A(%3F%3A(%3F%3Cviewcode%3E%5C(view%5Cd%2B%5C))%7C(%3F%3Ccolorcode%3E%5Cb%5BA-Z0-9%5D%7B2%2C3%7D))%3F(%3F%3A_%5BA-Z%5D)%3F%5Cr%3F%24&i=507920%20STLI_Q%0D%0A158035%20STLI%20Ocean%20EHC_Q%0D%0A158035%20STLI%20White%20WE_Q%0D%0A306002%20FMV%20SPIN%20FUCHSIA%202YP%0D%0A507918%20STLI%20(view002)_Q%0D%0A306002%20STL%20AQUA%20WBP%0D%0A123456%20STLI%20Ocean%20EHCD_Q&o=m)

The main change is that I added a word boundary `\b` at the start of the `colorcode` pattern, and changed the limiting quantifier to `{2,3}` to match 2 or 3 uppercase ASCII letters or digits.

I also removed some capturing groups (`(\s)?` > `\s*`, you may use `\s?` if there can be one or zero whitespaces) and turned  the "container" group for `viewcode` and `colorcode` groups into a non-capturing one.

To match entries with no colorcode and viewcode, I made the whole "container" non-capturing group optional by adding a `?` quantifier.

[image]

Comment: Thats great. It worked. This worked as well ^(?<productno>\d{6})\s(?<mattype>\w+).*?(\s)?((?<colorcode>\b[A-Z0-9]{2,3})*|(?<viewcode>\(view\d+\))*)(?:_[A-Z])?$

Comment: this works like a charm and the output you have shown is really very helpful. Thank you so much.